# how to create postgresql database using linux commandline

Tags: centos, postgresql

I have tried to create a postgresql database from linux(CentOS) command line by executing the following,

```
psql -U admin -p55432 postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE TEST_DB"
```

Created database name appeared as "test_db". I need to create database in upper case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL unquoted names are case-insensitive. So I do not see special reason to need of Upper case database name. But you can try something like:

```
psql -U admin -p55432 postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE \"TEST_DB\""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `createdb(1)` command, installed with Postgres, to create a database with an uppercase name without having to use quoting:

```
createdb -U admin -p55432 TEST_DB
```

Unless you *want* the database to be owned by `admin`, you should probably also set an owner using the `-O` flag.

*Note:* There’s also an accompanying `dropdb(1)` command.

You can read more about the Postgres command-line tools [in the official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/reference-client.html).